# Sed: Regex doesn't match and I have no idea why

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a long list of commands (most of them sed) piped together, the sed where my problem is gets input that looks like this:

```
v5.3-rc4/
v4.9.123/
```

and it should turn them into something like this:

```
v5.03-rc4/
v4.09.123/
```

My current attempt looks like this:

```
sed 's/v\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]\)\((\.[0-9]*)?(-rc[0-9]*)?\)\//v\1.0\2\3\//g'
```

I have already double-checked this in a RegEx-debugger and it seems to be correct. Can anyone tell me, what's wrong with this?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to sort strings by version? Or why do you want zero padded numbers here?

Comment: `?` is not part of sed regular expressions. GNU sed supports it as an extension with `\?`, or you could use `sed -E` and just `?` (but then you must not escape the parentheses).

Comment: here's an `awk` solution " `echo "v5.3-rc4/" | awk '{split($0,arr,".");split(arr[2],vers,"-");printf("%s.%02d-%s\n",arr[1],vers[1],vers[2])}'` :Result : `v5.03-rc4/` When the major version of your software execeeds `9.99`, then you can use the `%02d` trick for the first number (after parsing it out) ;-) Good luck

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks, it still doesn't seem to work that way, but that is probably the main problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly try to do, but what about change `.` to `.0`?

```
sed 's/\./.0/' file
v5.03-rc4/
v4.09.123/
```

Comment: It was like 3 am when I initially wrote the script and this doesn't solve the problem, but yea, it would probably work, too. (I would have to search for corner cases)